# I want to use custom png instead of canvas.drawcircle function. How can do it?

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

int currentX = maze.getCurrentX(),currentY = maze.getCurrentY();
        //draw the ball

```
    canvas.drawCircle((currentX * totalCellWidth)+(cellWidth/2),   //x of center
              (currentY * totalCellHeight)+(cellWidth/2),  //y of center
              (cellWidth*0.45f),                           //radius
              ball);

    //draw the finishing point indicator
    canvas.drawText("F",
                    (mazeFinishX * totalCellWidth)+(cellWidth*0.25f),
                    (mazeFinishY * totalCellHeight)+(cellHeight*0.75f),
                    ball);
}
```

Comment: Put the png in your resource folder and set it as background drawable on your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the png to your `drawable` folder. then you can create a `Bitmap` using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resourceId);`. The bitmap can be drawn on the canvas using `canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bmp, Rect source, Rect dest, Paint p)`. `bmp` is the bitmap to be drawn, obviously, `source` is the part of the bitmap that schould be drawn (in your case the whole bitmap), `dest` is the location on the canvas where the bitmap is drawn, `p` is the paint, which you don't need, so just use `null`.

Comment: Than you very much indeed :)